# How to solve pipeline hazards using stalls?

Tags: computer-architecture, hardware, mips

So, I have the following code, which should run on a five-stage pipeline (Fetch, Decode, Execute, Memory, Write). Now, we need only to consider read-after-write data dependencies and find the total clock cycles needed to execute the instructions.

The code is as follows:

```
lw $t1, 0($t0)
lw $t2, 4($t0)
add $t3, $t1, $t2
sw $t3, 12($t0)
lw $t4, 8($t0)
add $t5, $t1, $t4
sw $t5, 16($t0)
```

What I have done is find the data dependency (RAW) and then tried to put appropriate stalls which I think is the minimal stalls required. The following is the diagram I could think of:

```
F1 D1 E1 M1 W1
   F2 D2 E2 M2 W2
      F3 [   3  ] D3 E3 M3 W3
         F4 [       6       ] D4 E4 M4 W4
            F5 D5 E5 M5 W5
               F6 [   3  ] D6 E6 M6 W6
                  F7 [       6       ] D7 E7 M7 W7
```

Calculating using the above diagram, I get the answer to be 17 clock cycles. But, I am not sure if this approach is correct. And can this approach be extended for any questions or complications arise?

Also, my basic understanding of pipeline is make every unit as busy as possible. Thus there would be moments where F,D,E,M,W all of these are busy for different instructions. But, the approach I have taken in general might cause two decodes to occur simultaneously. Which I don't think is what pipelining does.

Edit: Forwarding is not supported.
[image: Data path in the processor I am using]
[image: add Instructions]
[image: sw, lw Instructions]

Comment: Is forwarding from MEM to EX supported, or not?

Comment: @jonk No forwarding is not supported. It is just the classic 5-stage Pipeline.

Comment: Then just considering the first 4 instructions would not that be 12 cycles? I think you show 14? Why?

Comment: @jonk Could you elaborate on how it would be? Like the fourth instructions actually needs the data from the previous instructions. So, its decode stage should start after the previous instruction is completed (6 stalls). And the third instruction requires the second and the first instructions to complete before its decode execution. Thus, we have 3 stalls. So, in total, 14. Could you show how it is 12?

Comment: I'd rather not, just yet. It also depends upon some of the architecture. For example, it's not necessary to hold up the ID and EX phases for the sw instruction as they can still be used to compute 12($t0). It's only in the MEM phase that a dependency on $t3 is actually required/recognized and needs to cause a stall until the previous add instruction performs its WB phase. So it could even be shorter. I was just pushing you for more information. I'm not reading your textbook nor taking your class so the *full* context isn't clear to me, yet.

Comment: @jonk I have attached the Datapath, and also how sw, lw, add instructions are executed. Could you kindly check if this is the information you needed to understand the question, or I should add anymore.

Comment: I guess I was thinking [along these lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UP3g.png), in terms of 12 cycles. That's partly because I thought your register file would only support 2 parallel reads and sw needs to supply the offset and one other register in the ID phase, not $t3, which should be carried along the path elsewhere as a reference for the MEM phase. In any case, it is time for me to return to bed. Not write more. Tomorrow, I'll pick it up and read your addition for better information to apply if others haven't completed it, already. If ID must pass along $t3 'elsewhere' then you're right.